# Instagram Receiving the same images via pagination

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to work with the Instagram API, but seem to have hit a bump that I can't get past. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
private function getInstagram()
    {
        $images = array();
        if(SERVER == 'test'){
            $tag = 'dog';
        } else {
            $tag = 'cat';
        }
        $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{$tag}/media/recent?access_token=".INSTAGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN;
        $instagram = json_decode(curl_get_contents($url));

        for($x=0; $x < 7; $x++){
            if(is_array($instagram->data)){
                foreach($instagram->data as $pic){
                    $images[$x][] = $pic->images->low_resolution->url;
                }
                $newUrl = $url .'&next_min_id='.$instagram->pagination->next_min_id;
                $instagram = json_decode(curl_get_contents($newUrl));
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return $images;
    }
```

For some reason I keep getting the same 7 images returned even on subsequent calls using the next_min_id. Does anyone see anything that I'm doing particularly wrong? Thanks.

Comment: why dont you just use the `next_url` to make the next call ?

Comment: next_url isn't being provided in the JSON response
`..."pagination": {
    "next_min_id": "AQDNIquEcGajBjQwif1TsZYpe3Fmy18DXnWNMixQRXcVS0EO0l8svJxrw0L66baYOWhIv-SwEsOgU0RUcmr0noaru6OmOTkOkp2s6KHj1zu8uQ",
    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
    "min_tag_id": "AQDNIquEcGajBjQwif1TsZYpe3Fmy18DXnWNMixQRXcVS0EO0l8svJxrw0L66baYOWhIv-SwEsOgU0RUcmr0noaru6OmOTkOkp2s6KHj1zu8uQ"
  },...`

Answer (score 0):

Use `max_tag_id` in the API to get next set of 20 posts. `next_max_id` is depreciated.

You should have `next_url`, if not you may be in sandbox mode. You can only get 20 posts in sandbox mode, when you go live, you will have `next_url` and will be able to get next set of 20 posts.